# jquery calendar with events after

Tags: jquery, events, calendar

I am using jquery calendar. I want to highlight different dates and show date events after the calendar. The following is the image which shows events.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
    });
});
</script>

<div class="my">
<div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dates = [
    [2013, 3, 7],
    [2013, 3, 9],
    [2013, 3, 25]
];

$('#calendar').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date){
        var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
        for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i)
            if (year == dates[i][0] && month == dates[i][2] - 1 &&  day == dates[i][2])
                return [false, 'ui-state-highlight ui-state-active'];

        return [false];
    }
});
</script>
```

I have reach till following image.

[image]

In the first image you can see events after calendar. I want to show a selected event after the calendar, just like in the 1st image.

Comment: in first image u can see events after calendar. i want to show selected event after calendar. just like 1st image.

Comment: @SalmanRazakMemon I'd suggest you include your question too in the post instead of comments.